# Unity layers not working as I want

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, layer

So I'm very new to Unity and creating my first 2D game, It will have a player, monsters, platforms and a static background image.

So What I've done is set a 2D sprite as a background image which is on the default layer. I also got a character from the asset store that I just pulled in to the game and set to User layer 8 (player).

The platforms randomly spawn on the map and was not visible through the background at first but when I set the sprite sortingorder to 1 they were visible.

Now for the monsters. They are also from the asset store but inserted into the game via C# code. If I have a the background on screen they are still not visible even if i set the GameObject.layer = 8 for them(to same layer as player). Why? What Is the problem here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has two types of layers, the ones you're changing are not the ones that determine drawing order, you need to change the SortingLayer and OrderInLayer parameters in the SpriteRenderer component.
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/sorting-layers

If you're only using sprites then you can keep all of them in the same SortingLayer and change the OrderInLayer of the background to something like -100.
If you're  using 3d models, youre gonna need to manually set the positions of the objects closer or away from the camera (and keep all the sprites on the default SortingLayer).

Comment: Yeah the monsters are not using sprites, they are "prefabs"(?) with the components animation, rigidbody, rigidbody , box collider2d and a child object or whatever it is called with a skinned mesh renderer.

Comment: I'm also trying to add some environment objects like trees and such (also prefabs) that have mesh filter, mesh renderer and mesh collider components. Part of them are visible through the background. I'm not getting the hang of this unfortunately :/

Comment: My guess would be to order them with the z value, change your view to 3D and just place the background far away from the camera, and the prefabs closer. I imagine your camera is set to Orthographic, so it wont affect the projection.